# java.util.zip.ZipException: ZIP_Read: error reading zip file

Tags: java, zip

When running the following code:

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(new File("/fodler", "zipfile.zip"));
ZipEntry zipEntry = zipFile.entries().nextElement(); 
LineNumberReader reader = new LineNumberReader(new InputStreamReader(zipFile.getInputStream(zipEntry), "8859_1"), 1024 * 1024);
reader.readLine();
```

Sometimes I get the following exception:

> java.util.zip.ZipException: ZIP_Read: error reading zip file
>   at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
>   at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1200(ZipFile.java:31)
>   at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:459)
>   at java.util.zip.ZipFile$1.fill(ZipFile.java:242)
>   at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:141)
>   at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:264)
>   at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:306)
>   at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158)
>   at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:167)
>   at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:136)
>   at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:299)
>   at java.io.LineNumberReader.readLine(LineNumberReader.java:182)

When restarting the service it works as expected.
Any idea?

Comment: which service? your question may be missing some key information.

Comment: Do you close all readers/streams if you don't need them anymore?

Comment: @Jayan When I say service I mean when I rerun the code.

Comment: How do you close the new InputStreamReader in the code above?

Comment: @soilworker I provided part of the code. I close it with reader.close();

Comment: Could you try to explicitly close the InputStreamReader also?